# Apache HttpClient negotiate handle second 401 response

Tags: java, authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x, spnego

I am attempting to access an HTTP service that uses `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate` for authentication.

I am using HttpClient using the example from Apache.  I see two requests sent.
First an initial request with response 401 and headers indicating that `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate` is used (expected). Then there is a second request sent with the Authenticate header and token.  The server then responds with another 401 and it's own authenticate token in the header.

When I try making the same request through `curl --negotiate` I see this same behavior, except curl then sends a third request containing a modified token which finally is successful.

The [Apache tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/tutorial/html/authentication.html#SPNEGO) has this to say about it:

> If more processing is required another HTTP 401 is returned to the
>   client with more data in the the WWW-Authenticate header. Client takes
>   the info and generates another token passing this back in the
>   Authorization header until complete.

Which implies that this is a normal thing that can happen but there is no explanation on what to do when it does.

How can I achieve this to authenticate with the HttpClient (or if there is a different way that's easier to do with a different library I open to that as well).  My code, based on the example from HttpClient, is below.

```java
public class ClientKerberosAuthentication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "login.conf");
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "krb5.conf");
        System.setProperty("sun.security.spnego.debug", "true");
        System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly","false");
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            Credentials use_jaas_creds = new Credentials() {
                public String getPassword() {
                    return null;
                }
                public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
                    return null;
                }
            };
            httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope(null, -1, null),
                    use_jaas_creds);
            HttpUriRequest request =
                    RequestBuilder.post("http://webservice")
                    .setEntity(EntityBuilder.create().setFile(new File("data.txt")).build())
                    .build();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            if (entity != null) {
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
            }
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        } finally {
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe This has nothing to do with angular, nor is there any web browser involved.

Comment: Sorry, I misread that completely!

Comment: What do you mean no web browser involved? As you said: "I am using HttpClient".   I'm mis-understanding something here.

Comment: @JohnRSmith https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ is an http client library for Java.  Nothing here is running in a web browser.